# How to make several objects reference the same object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

I am currently trying to make several sets reference only one set. So I used simple copy for mutable objects, but the output is different from my expectations.

code

```
Set1 = {1, 2, 3}
Set2 = Set1
Set3 = {10, 11, 12}
Set4 = Set3
Set3 = Set2
print(Set1, Set2, Set3, Set4)
```

my output

```
{1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3} {10, 11, 12}
```

expected output

```
{1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 3}
```

Is there any general way to make objects reference the same thing?

Edit:
Thanks to comment from Neeraj, I now understand what is the problem. But I want to change the reference of not only Set3 but also Set4 by one assigning code, if possible.
So the question is,

'Is there any way to make several objects that previously referenced the same object reference the other object at once?'

Comment: how is it different from expectation? You are assigning set3 to set4 and then set2 to set3. Please elaborate more on this?

Comment: This output is what you wrote

Comment: swap those two lines and it will be like you expect.

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about what `=` means in Python. I recommend [reading up on that](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: (Particularly for sets, it sounds like what you really need might be a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), not a bunch of Python `set` objects. Also, seriously, read [that other article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) - your latest edit suggests you're still misunderstanding the relationship between objects and variables.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but really hacky way, is to just store the set in a list, and have all variables reference the list

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `copy`, from `import copy`. [Refer to that](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/). With `copy`, the changes will follow if it is the desired result.